# Webbench fork error

Tags: web, web-testing, webtest

I wanna use webbench to test my website, I use mac.
When I did  `webbench -c 50 -t 30 http://XXXX` It works well

But when I did `webbench -c 5000 -t 30 http://XXXX` 
It reported error like this:

```
problems forking worker no. 98
fork failed.: Operation timed out
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem too, you can switch ApachBench to test your website.
See this webpage for detail: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html